# Return multiple DB2 rows using Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, db2

I am writing SQL query in Excel to fetch DB2 table rows.

My query is only fetching one row that satisfy the WHERE clause, even though there are multiple records in DB2.

This is the my existing code:

```css
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM XXX WHERE CONTRACT_NUM='ABCD';"
Set rs = conn.Execute(strSQL)
    
Dim fldCount As Integer
Dim iCol As Integer

fldCount = rs.Fields.Count
    
For iCol = 1 To fldCount
  Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & iCol).Value = rs.Fields(iCol - 1).Name & ":" &     rs.Fields(iCol - 1).Value
Next
```

Is there anything that I can include that will solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop through the list of recordset to fetch next next records.

```
Do While rs.EOF = False
For iCol = 1 To fldCount
  Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & iCol).Value = rs.Fields(iCol - 1).Name & ":" & rs.Fields(iCol - 1).Value
Next
rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

The above code fetches all the records row by row. Also you need to make sure the each record is storing in different columns. Here you have mentioned A column for first record.Similarly you need to increment or change the columns for next available records.

Hope it will useful for you.

Comment: Seems like this is working. Thanks for the quick answer.